# Using while loops to plot points in java

Tags: java, bluej

Hey guys I'm working on an assignment where I have to plot several different points within a range using a while loop to only plot the points while the numbers entered are within the acceptable range. Since I'm doing this for class we're using Bluej and premade tests to determine if the problems have been correctly solved, yet the tests only fail without giving me much insight as to what I did wrong. The working range for our assignment is 0 - 290 and whenever the user enters in a point outside that range the loop is supposed to print "Done", which it does successfully every time I try. I've tried messing with the numbers some to see if anything helps but I keep getting failures. I'd really appreciate any insight into whats going on, thank you.

```
 /**
 * Plotter.java
 * 
 */

//Put any imports below this line.
import java.util.Scanner;

/**
 * Short, one-line description of Plotter class here.
 * 
 * Optionally, include a paragraph that provides a more 
 * detailed description.
 *
 * @author Nicholas Thomas
 * @version 3/18/2018
 */
public class Plotter
{
    /** Main method of the program.
     * Method main
     *
     * @param args A parameter
     */
    public static void main(String[]args)
    {
        Plotter plotter = new Plotter();
        plotter.drawAxes();
        Scanner keyboard = new Scanner(System.in);
        plotter.plotPoints(keyboard);
    }

    /** Method dealing with x axis.
     * Method drawXAxis
     *
     */
    public void drawXAxis()
    {
        for (int x = 0; x < 300; x += 5)
        {
            new Square(x, 147);
        }
    }

    /** Method to draw ticks using x.
     * Method drawOneXTick
     *
     * @param x A parameter
     */
    public void drawOneXTick(int x)
    {
        for (int y = 137; y < 160; y += 5)
        {
            new Square(x, y);
        }
    }

    /** Method to draw all ticks.
     * Method drawAllXTicks
     *
     */
    public void drawAllXTicks()
    {
        for (int x = 7; x < 300; x+= 20)
        {
            drawOneXTick(x);
        }
    }

    /** Method dealing with y axis. 
     * Method drawYAxis
     *
     */
    public void drawYAxis()
    {
        for (int y = 0; y < 300; y += 5)
        {
            new Square(147, y);
        }
    }

    /** Method to draw one y tick.
     * Method drawOneYTick
     *
     * @param y A parameter
     */
    public void drawOneYTick(int y)
    {
        for (int x = 137; x < 160; x += 5)
        {
            new Square(x, y);
        }
    }

    /** Method to draw all y ticks.
     * Method drawAllYTicks
     *
     */
    public void drawAllYTicks()
    {
        for (int y = 7 ; y < 300; y+= 20)
        {
            drawOneYTick(y);
        }
    }

    /** Method to draw axes.
     * Method drawAxes
     *
     */
    public void drawAxes()
    {
        drawXAxis();
        drawYAxis();
        drawAllXTicks();
        drawAllYTicks();
    }

    /** Method to plot points.
     * Method plotPoints
     *
     * @param keyboard A parameter
     */
    public void plotPoints(Scanner keyboard)
    {
        int x = 0, y = 0;
        while (( x >= 0 && x <= 290) && (y >= 0 && y <= 290))
        {
            System.out.print("Enter an x and y coordinate: ");
            x = keyboard.nextInt(); 
            y = keyboard.nextInt();
            new Circle(x,y);
            System.out.print("Done");
        }
        while(( x < 0 && x > 290) && (y < 0 && y > 290))
        {
            System.out.print("Done");
        }
    }

    /** Method to plot points.
     * Method plotPointsProper
     *
     * @param keyboard A parameter
     */
    public void plotPointsProper(Scanner keyboard)
    {

    }
}
```

This in particular is the part giving me trouble, I only added the second while loop to see if it would help any, but no luck.

```
public void plotPoints(Scanner keyboard)
{
    int x = 0, y = 0;
    while (( x >= 0 && x <= 290) && (y >= 0 && y <= 290))
    {
        System.out.print("Enter an x and y coordinate: ");
        x = keyboard.nextInt(); 
        y = keyboard.nextInt();
        new Circle(x,y);
        System.out.print("Done");
    }
    while(( x < 0 && x > 290) && (y < 0 && y > 290))
    {
        System.out.print("Done");
    }
}
```

The errors I'm getting are telling me that too many points are being plotted, I'm wondering if the initialization of my x and y variables might have something to do with my problem or if its the way I've written my while loop? Again, thanks for any hints or advice you guys have.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! To better assist, you we need the exact errors that you are getting. Are they compile time errors? Or run time errors? Or output from some kind of testing program?

Comment: Can you identify which points it is plotting that it should not?

Comment: Where are the Circle and Square classes?

Comment: It's a bit hard to understand what you're trying to do. As the answer below sort of explains, you should probably move the "Done" print outside the loop. Also, since you are checking before the nextInt it's possible for an out of range point to be plotted,

Comment: @Scoobert D did my answer below work for you?

Comment: Yes it did, thank you very much. Definitely what I needed to see.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I've modified your plotPoints function to make it work with the constraints you specified.

```
public void plotPoints(Scanner keyboard)
{
    int x = 0, y = 0;
    while (true)
    {
        System.out.print("Enter an x and y coordinate: ");
        x = keyboard.nextInt(); 
        y = keyboard.nextInt();
    if(( x < 0 || x > 290) || (y < 0 || y > 290)) break;
        new Circle(x,y);
    }
    System.out.print("Done");
}
```

In the code that you shared, if you entered x>290, it will still make the call to `new Circle(x,y)` and the loop will only terminate on the next iteration. By putting the condition inside the while loop, we can break the loop exactly when we need to.